# How to set a column as a range variable as long as there is data in it?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like excel to input the entire column with the title "Section" into the range variable 'sectioncol'.

```
Set sectioncol = range(range("A1:R1").Find(what:="Section", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Address & ":" & range("A1:R1").Find(what:="Section", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).End(xlDown).Address)
```

I was expecting the range variable to return the cells containing data under the section column.

Answer (score 0):

That line is too long (hard to read), and will fail if `"Section"` is not found.

Better to break it up into intermediate steps:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:R1").Find( _
    What:="Section", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then ' Test if Section was found
    Dim sectioncol As Range
    Set sectioncol = Range(rng, Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reference a Data Column Range

**(Long) Educational (Using `Find`)**

```vb
Sub ReferenceDataColumnRange()

    ' Define constants.
    Const HEADER_TITLE As String = "Section"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the table range.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Debug.Print "Entire Range:      " & rg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Reference the header row range.
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(1)
    Debug.Print "Header Row Range:  " & hrg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Attempt to reference the header cell.
    Dim hCell As Range: Set hCell = hrg.Find(HEADER_TITLE, _
        hrg.Cells(hrg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    
    ' Check if the header cell was found (referenced).
    If hCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The header """ & HEADER_TITLE & """ was not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Debug.Print "Header Cell:       " & hCell.Address(0, 0) _
    
    ' Check if there is any data below the headers.
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data below the header """ & HEADER_TITLE & """.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' Reference the data column range (no headers).
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns(hCell.Column - rg.Column + 1) _
        .Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    Debug.Print "Data Column Range: " & crg.Address(0, 0)

End Sub
```

**(Short) Practical (Using `Application.Match`)**

```
Sub ReferenceDataColumnRangeShort()
    
    Dim crg As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Dim cIndex: cIndex = Application.Match("Section", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then ' header found
            If .Rows.Count > 1 Then ' data found
                Set crg = .Columns(cIndex).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
    If crg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    MsgBox crg.Address(0, 0), vbInformation

End Sub
```

- Note that you can also write the first code in a short version.
- It's up to you to determine which details are important (known) in each particular case.